# Doctrine2 custom uniqueness in slugs

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, unique, slug

I'm trying to make unique url slugs for an entity called Page.  The slugs should only be unique over Pages related to a Site.

So url slugs for pages {site1.com/about, site2.com/about} are unique enough to identify the page.  Having pages unique over all sites would be unappealing:  site3.com/about-21 is weird.

I tried to do this with DoctrineExtensions sluggable, but got the suggestion [to write](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/issues/410) something custom.  Below is my first attempt.  Because I can't get the EntityManager in the Entity, I'm having trouble getting the other slugs to check if they're unique.

Any suggestions?

```
/** 
 * Slugify Title.  To "re-slugify", set titleSlug to empty
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */
public function slugifyTitle($override = false) {
  // We only slugify is titleSlug is empty
  if (empty($this->titleSlug) or $override) {

    if (!empty($this->title)) {
      // Title not empty?  slugify the title.  SluggableListener line 220
      $slug = Urlizer::transliterate($this->title);
    } else {
      // Title empty?  make a slug based on the classname
      $slug = get_class($this);
    }
    $this->titleSlug = Urlizer::urlize($slug);  
    $this->titleSlug = $this->uniqueify($this->titleSlug);
    echo $this->titleSlug;
  };
}

/**
 * Make the string unique in the domain of:  This site, this pagetype
 */
public function uniqueify($someSlug) {
  //return $someSlug . rand();
  // FIXME :-)
  $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
  $pageType = get_class($this);
  $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT slug FROM Powma\ServiceBundle\Entity\$pageType pt");
  $slugs = $query->getResult();
  // find a unique one.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for reference, the solution was to make an event listener as described here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html